# How do I calculate impact force between two 2D objects in Unity 3D

Tags: math, unity-game-engine, 2d

I am working on a 2D space shooter game and I make all the player ship movements directly to the transform of the ship and not via physics (so no AddForce here). Now I would like to make the player ship bounce of any asteroids it hits but using the build in physics won't work well with my movement code that uses the transform directly, so I figured I should make some simple physics calculations for this my self and then add the calculated force to the movement force I use on the transform. Is this the way to go?

But I can not figure out how to make the correct calculations for the force, can you guys help me out here? My simple idea is to get the angle between the player ship and the asteroid and then convert this angle to a vector and then add the resulting force vector to the movement force. Will this work and how do I do it? Or is there a better way?

I have added a image to illustrate my idea (the idea that I can not figure out how to make the calculations for), the circle is the asteroid, the triangle is the ship, the dotted triangle is the ship with the movement and the collision force added, the green line is the movement force (always forward/up), the red line illustrates the angle from the player ship to the asteroid and the blue line is the collision force. Makes sense?

Also how do I calculate the correct angle and force vector for that angle? I always struggle with math :( I have tried to get the angle and create a force vector for that angle in the following code. I do not take real force into account I only try to get the direction and normalize it to make it a fixed size, and I then apply it to the ship position simply to test my math and see if the vector is in the right direction, but it is not. Can you guys help me with this also?

```
Vector2 toVector = otherCollider.transform.position - transform.position;
float angleToTarget = Vector2.Angle(transform.position, toVector);
Vector3 angleVelocity = new Vector3((float)Mathf.Cos(angleToTarget), (float)Mathf.Sin(angleToTarget), 0);
angleVelocity = angleVelocity.normalized * 1.0f;

transform.position = transform.position + angleVelocity;
```

[image]

Thank you
Søren

Answer (score 0):

The angle of the ship in relation to the asteroid will give you the velocity for the x and y axis. Use one point in your level as the origin `(0, 0)`. You can treat each object as a dot to make your life simple.

You can calculate Force by using [Newton's Laws of motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_laws_of_motion). Mainly focus on the second law.

> F = ma

Which means Force equals mass times acceleration. So all you have to do is give mass to your object and find out how much acceleration each object has the instant before impact.

You have probably given your objects velocity instead of acceleration. So you can use [Kinematics](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/1DKin/Lesson-6/Kinematic-Equations).

> v_f^2 = v_i^2 + 2*a*d

`v_f` is the final velocity.

`v_i` the initial velocity.

`d` the distance your object has traveled.

`a` is acceleration.

---

Or maybe Momentum is easier for you.

> p = m v

Comment: My asteroid is always dead still in space. I do have the velocity of my ship, but what is meant by the distance my object has traveled? It can travel a long way... I also have mass so maybe momentum, but how do I apply this new force? I mean it has to be applied as a vector in the correct direction relative to the impact some how?

Comment: Yeah related it to the ship not the asteroid. Although, if the asteroid is moving too, momentum based collisions are the best. I take one thing back, you do need the angle of the ship in relationship to the asteroid. Once you have the angle then you can find the velocity on y and x axis.

Comment: Thank you. Can you help me get the correct calculation of the force vector direction also, I am getting it all wrong. I updated the question with this question also.